# Learning python Logging and @contextmanager, when i use "with as" , the result is confused

Tags: python, contextmanager

```
@contextmanager
def log_level(level,name):
    logger=logging.getLogger(name)
    old_level=logger.getEffectiveLevel()
    try:
        logger.setLevel(level)
        yield logger
    finally:
        logger.setLevel(old_level)
with log_level(logging.DEBUG,'my_logger') as logger:
    logger.debug('debug error')
    logging.debug('logging error')
```

the output is None，However when i add logging.debug('')before with as
the output is DEBUG:my_logger:debug error

Comment: Is that your actual indentation? Because as written, that `try`/`finally`, which logically should be part of `log_level`, isn't. Also, is this your complete code? Because you never called *any* initial logging configuration function here.

Comment: Thank you，try/finally should be part of log_level，This is the complete code, i copy the code from Effective Python, the initial logging configuration shold be ' logger=logging.getLogger(name)'